# Fetch async/await data and them show/return in html

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

I am new with async/await fetch. Below is my HTML code

```
  <div id="content">
    <!-- Data will appear here as list -->
  </div>
```

below is my vanilla JS code

```
function loadData() {
  const element = document.getElementById("content");
  element.innerHTML = getTemplate();
}

function getTemplate() {
  async function getPosts() {
    try {
      const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
      const response = await fetch(url);
      console.log(response);

      if (response.ok) {
        const res = await response.json();
        return res;
      } else {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }

  getPosts().then(data => console.log(data));

  //How I return data from here so it will update in the DOM

};

loadData();
```

How show data as list after async/wait fetch my data using vanilla JS.

Comment: result of `getTemplate` is asynchronous, so it returns a Promise - therefore `element.innerHTML = getTemplate();` will always result in `element.innerHTML` being a Promise converted to string ... i.e. `[object Object]` .. no matter what you do, you can't get a synchronous result when asynchrony is involved

Comment: You need to change `loadData` so that it will respect the asynchrony, and wait for the promise. The easiest solution would be `function loadData() {
  const element = document.getElementById("content");
  element.innerHTML = await getPosts();
}`, but you can also use `getPosts().then(data => { element.innerHTML = data; })`

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a problem to reorganize the code a bit, try the following. On how to return, remember an asynchronous function returns a promise and you must work in context, so I get the promise of the response to call `getPosts` and with the data I get the template that I then give in #content

```js
function loadData() {
  const element = document.querySelector("div#content");

  getPosts().then(posts => {
    const template = getTemplate(posts);

    element.innerHTML = template;
  });
}

async function getPosts() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  const response = await fetch(url);

  return await response.json();
}

function getTemplate(posts) {
  const rows = posts.map(postToRowView).join("");

  return `<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Body</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>${rows}</tbody>
  </table>`;
}

function postToRowView(post) {
  return `<t>
    <td>${post.title}</td>
    <td>${post.body}</td>
  </tr>`;
}

loadData();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```
function loadData() {
  const element = document.getElementById("content");
  getTemplate(element);
}

function getTemplate(element) {
  .....

  getPosts().then(data => {
     console.log(data));
     element.innerHTML = data;
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. Mark `getPosts()` , `loadData()` and `getTemplate()` an `async` function
2. And then just `return await getPosts()`
3. Lastly, in `loadData()` you `await getTemplate()`